# Error: uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:cloud_firestore]

Tags: flutter, firebase, gradle, google-cloud-firestore

I wanted to connect my flutter project to my cloud firestore. But it is giving me this error
`

```
C:\Users\Syamira Rahman\AndroidStudioProjects\fyp_service_jet\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:cloud_firestore] C:\Users\Syamira Rahman\AndroidStudioProjects\fyp_service_jet\build\cloud_firestore\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:cloud_firestore] C:\Users\Syamira Rahman\AndroidStudioProjects\fyp_service_jet\build\cloud_firestore\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s

┌─ Flutter Fix ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ The plugin cloud_firestore requires a higher Android SDK version.                             │
│ Fix this issue by adding the following to the file C:\Users\Syamira                           │
│ Rahman\AndroidStudioProjects\fyp_service_jet\android\app\build.gradle:                        │
│ android {                                                                                     │
│   defaultConfig {                                                                             │
│     minSdkVersion 19                                                                          │
│   }                                                                                           │
│ }                                                                                             │
│                                                                                               │
│ Note that your app won't be available to users running Android SDKs below 19.                 │
│ Alternatively, try to find a version of this plugin that supports these lower versions of the │
│ Android SDK.                                                                                  │
│ For more information, see:                                                                    │
│ https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration                 │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I have tried changing the minSdkVersion to 19 but it's still giving me error.
It is asking me to use the multidex but when i configure the multidex, my authentication gets messed up and it wouldn't work. I'm a beginner with both firebase and flutter so I'm not quite sure what to do.
I managed to connect my flutter app with firestore and manage to create authentication for my app. Its just the cloud firestore that is not working. Hope that anyone can help.

````
ERROR:D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 98764 > 65536)
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:151)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:138)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction.merge(DexMergingTask.kt:859)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction.run(DexMergingTask.kt:805)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.ProfileAwareWorkAction.execute(ProfileAwareWorkAction.kt:74)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:97)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:205)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:187)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.access$700(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:120)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:162)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:270)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:119)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:126)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, position: null
    at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_3.1.66.java:0)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.pO0.a(SourceFile:68)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.pO0.a(SourceFile:28)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.pO0.a(SourceFile:27)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.pO0.b(SourceFile:3)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:11)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:136)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.internal.b: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 98764 > 65536)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.jl1.a(SourceFile:14)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.jl1.a(SourceFile:22)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.T.a(SourceFile:58)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.O.a(SourceFile:7)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.e.a(SourceFile:14)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.e.c(SourceFile:36)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(D8.java:187)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(D8.java:1)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.pO0.a(SourceFile:24)
    ... 41 more


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate
   > There was a failure while executing work items
      > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction
         > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
           The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
           Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
[!] App requires Multidex support

┌─ Flutter Fix ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Flutter multidex handling is disabled. If you wish to let the tool configure multidex, use the │
│ --multidex flag.                                                                               │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this error message

```
┌─ Flutter Fix ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ The plugin cloud_firestore requires a higher Android SDK version.                             │
│ Fix this issue by adding the following to the file C:\Users\Syamira                           │
│ Rahman\AndroidStudioProjects\fyp_service_jet\android\app\build.gradle:                        │
│ android {                                                                                     │
│   defaultConfig {                                                                             │
│     minSdkVersion 19                                                                          │
│   }                                                                                           │
│ }
```

Your minSdkVersion need to update at least 19. Open your `app/build.gradle` and set `minSdkVersion:22` I prefer at least 21.

[image]